# Javascript switch array values from boolean to string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this 2 dimensional array =

```
0: (3) [true, false, false]
1: (3) [true, true, false]
2: (3) [true, true, true]
3: (3) [false, false, false]
```

The position in the array represents the same in each i.e 0 = "Learner" 1 = "Manager", 2 = "ClientAdmin"

I want a new 2 dimensional array that looks like below

```
0: (3) ["Learner"]
1: (3) ["Learner", "Manager"]
2: (3) ["Learner", "Manager", "ClientAdmin"]
3: (3) []
```

I have tried

```
selectedAudienceMandatoryArrayText = []

this.selectedAudienceMandatoryArray.forEach( (isArray, index) => {
          if (isArray[0] == true) {
            this.selectedAudienceMandatoryArrayText[index].push("Learner");
          }
          if (isArray[1] == true) {
            this.selectedAudienceMandatoryArrayText[index].push("Manager");
          }
          if (isArray[2] == true) {
            this.selectedAudienceMandatoryArrayText[index].push("ClientAdmin"); 
          }
        }
```

but I get the error:  `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

What is the most efficient way to do this. ES6 solutions welcome.

Comment: Sorry it is part of the angular component I am working on. selectedAudienceMandatoryArrayText = []. I'll edit the question

Comment: `[][0]` is undefined, so `undefined.push` is where your error is coming from

Comment: Ok. How do push to  selectedAudienceMandatoryArrayText create a 2 dimensional array? Otherwise I will get ["Learner", "Learner", "Manager", "Learner", "Manager", "ClientAdmin"] I don't want them all in one array. I need them in a 2 dimensional array.

Comment: `selectedAudienceMandatoryArrayText.push([])` as the first thing in your forEach to make a new element at the same index as the index you are processing on the other array

Comment: I understand thanks, but I need to change the logic. Can I use an if inside the push?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check if the flag is set, then take the value from `roles` with the index or return an empty array.

```js
const
    roles = ["Learner", "Manager", "ClientAdmin"],
    data = [[true, false, false], [true, true, false], [true, true, true], [false, false, false]],
    result = data.map(a => a.flatMap((f, i) => f ? roles[i] : []));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Works great. Just need to get my head around it. Not seen flatMap before.

Comment: have a look here: [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
selectedAudienceMandatoryArrayText = [];

this.selectedAudienceMandatoryArray.forEach(isArray => {
  const roles = [];
  
  if (isArray[0]) roles.push('Learner');
  if (isArray[1]) roles.push('Manager');
  if (isArray[2]) roles.push('ClientAdmin');
  
  selectedAudienceMandatoryArrayText.push(roles);
}
```

You could push to a new array for each loop, and at the end, push that to the other array.  This reduces having to keep track of the index for the outer array.